# Different Image Dimensions in Browser

Tags: css, image, dimensions

I've recently been exploring on a site in my free time, and ran across a peculiar circumstance. When viewing an image (direct link) from imageshack, it displays in two (or more) completely different, and sometimes blurry, dimensions.

For instance -- where an image might be small in Chrome or Vivaldi, appears in full scale in Safari or Firefox. Given the differences in the background, as I believe the former two are webkit based, where as the other two use their own engine, I'm not sure if this has something to do with it, as I couldn't detect any outright styling that would force such a difference.

The links are identical when viewed between browsers, on the same machine. Same results occur when attempting on another machine. Any idea as to what might cause this, and how to remedy it for a consistent experience?

Below is a single image link for an example -- one of many instances.
[Image](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img922/8854/0UXqDa.jpg)

My thanks ahead of time for the input and any feedback or assistance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Supplied image  displays identically in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Curious. I'll see if I can delve further and find the root of the cause, given I've checked on three machines at this point. Though I don't suspect it has anything to do with preferences, I'll check there as well.